# How to redirect a direct link to file to a web page? (with PHP & NGINX)

Tags: php, cookies, redirect, nginx

Basically, I'd like it to work like this:

1) if user clicks the download link on my site then download starts as expected

2) if user clicks the download link on third-party site then (s)he is redirected to my site (where download starts automatically shortly thereafter)

I don't want to serve files with PHP, as this is expensive. Maybe some cookie checking on NGINX's part is possible? Say, all paths

```
site.name/files/app_id/file_name.zip
```

should be redirected to

```
site.name/download/app_id
```

if cookie is not present.

Would appreciate any ideas/examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to `mod_rewrite`? You can redirect the users based on the domain in his referrer. Try [this](http://dmr.ath.cx/notes/rewrite.html).

don't forget that some users might not send referrers and are therefore not be able to download from your site at all.